# Building Durandal and Breeze with Weyland produces main-built.js which fails on deps (dependencies) undefined

Tags: breeze, durandal, weyland

I'm trying to build a Durandal project that uses Breeze 1.4.6 with the Weyland tool. So far I've succeeded in the task and a main-built.js is generated. However, when I run the main-built.js like this:

```
<script src="~/Areas/Email/App/main-built.js"></script>
```

I get an error in the following line (last shown):

```
define = function (name, deps, callback) {

    //This module may not have dependencies
    if (!deps.splice) {
```

Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined
```

This is because deps is undefined for Breeze. I'm using Google Chrome.

Any help on the topic?

Thank you very much!
Tommi

Comment: It looks like you're saying that 'deps' is another module that this one is dependent on, but I don't see that you've defined the dependent module to set up the 'deps' definition function. It may help if you posted the entire module or, even better, if you created a jsFiddle. In the interim, replacing your code with 'if (undefined === deps)' should get you around the error in that line.